# AvalonDock : Controling the Splitter position

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, avalondock

Using AvalonDock and Odyssey OutLookBar in a WPF Desktop application.
It doesn't make sense to have the vertical splitter in the ResizingPanel have full range of screen width. ResizeWidth as an attached property on the DockablePane does control the initial position. But then it can be moved from full left to right. Is there any way of controlling the range, or worst case fixing its position.

```
    <my:DockingManager Grid.Row="1" >
        <my:ResizingPanel x:Name="resizePanel" >
            <my:DockablePane my:ResizingPanel.ResizeWidth="200" >
                <my:DockableContent x:Name="outLookBar" Title="OutLookBar"
```

Also, what is ResizingPanel.EffectiveSize for, which needs a Size object, eg "100,100"

thanks
John

Answer (score 0):

You can try to set minimum size on each of the panes. No idea what EffectiveSize is for, but it sounds like it might be intended to be a read-only property similar to ActualWidth/Height.